# how to replace softtabs with hardtabs in sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace softtabs with hardtabs in sed. I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
sed -i 's/    /\t/g' path/to/file
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The file is unaltered.

Comment: Please define softtab.

Comment: a softtab is when you use a fixed number of spaces for indentation, as opposed to a hardtab which is simply a tab character.

Comment: if you're running this with an old `sed` on an old `unix`, then I don't think, for instance Sun 4 Sed, understand `\t`. For that sort of case, you just press the tab key while typing your cmd. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally someone posted a comment (then deleted it) about `unexpand` and that is working perfectly. I simply ran the following `unexpand -a -t4 myfile > myfile1`

Comment: You want [unexpand − convert spaces to tabs](http://man.cx/unexpand)

Comment: @gloo, you should add your own answer and accept. Best way to help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears what I was looking for was the `unexpand` command.

```
unexpand -a -t4 file > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file like this where all space is spaces and not tabs:

```
cat file
test    more data
here     are more
```

You can use

```
sed  's/   */\t/g'
```

or

```
sed  -r 's/  +/\t/g'
```

and get

```
test    more data
here    are more
```

Where it now have changed multiple spaces to tab